# RS-232c Digi scale is not sending any data

Tags: node.js, serial-port, node-serialport

I connected a Digi DS-781 digital scale to a PC through a Trendnet TU-S9 serial-to-usb converter cable.

Device manager finds the COM port just fine. Next I'm trying to use node-serialport to communicate with it (main goal is to get the values displayed on the scales screen).

```
const port = new serialport('COM3', {
  baudRate: 9600,
  parity: 'even',
  stopBits: 1,
  dataBits: 8
});

port.on('open', () => {
  console.log('Port opened');
});

port.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`Got data: ${data.toString()}`);
});

port.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(`Port error: ${err.message}`);
});

port.on('close', () => {
  console.log('Port closed');
});
```

The scale is setup accordingly so the serialport settings shown above match with the scale.

Then I run my node application. Connection gets established successfully, everything seems to work, but when I put something on the scale there's no output on the 'data' callback. The scale seems to be sending nothing. My expectation is that as soon as I put something on the scale it should transmit the data over to my node application (the scale is in "Standard stream" mode).

[image: Transmission mode]

Im starting to wonder there's another step I have to do before the scale sends me anything (although the documentation for the scale shows otherwise which can be found here https://www.marsden-weighing.co.uk/index.php/digi-ds-781-user-manual.html)

Comment: Try connecting to the scale with a terminal application (e.g. putty) to see if it's sending anything.

Comment: You will need to configure the equipment as described in pages 16 to 33 of the manual you are introducing. In particular, pages 20 and 21 will be RS232C related settings.

Comment: Also consider (manual paragraph 20.3. _Control Code and Characters_) that data is terminated by **CR** and text by **LF**. You probably need a parser such as **parser: serialport.parsers.readline('\n')**.

Comment: @luigif I tried parsers. But shouldn't the .on('data') callback light up as soon as there is any data? I will try your Putty suggestion.

Comment: The .on('data') event is fired by the parser when it believes that a complete chunk of data is received. Different parsers act differently. In your case a readline parser should be enough and maybe it's the default parser, not sure. You will find more on the docs https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport#parsers https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport/blob/master/packages/serialport/examples/readline.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The settings on my scale were off. The scale was not in "Continuous streaming" mode, but in some invalid mode.

On this specific scale SPEC 10 has to be "0001" and SPEC 11 (4'th bit of SPEC 10, that's what confused me in the specifications) "0000". This put the scale into streaming mode and it's now sending data continuously.

Comment: thanks for this, I am looking at this same model for UK clients. To confirm, is this the same scale you bought? It came standard with RS232? https://www.marsden-weighing.co.uk/index.php/digi-ds-781-price-computing-scale.html. I did find a manual online that mentions streaming, but the scale in the photo looks a little different: https://www.sbzsystems.com/download/DS-781%20Communication.pdf